# The method onStart(Context, int) is undefined for the type Object

Tags: android, int, oncreate, android-context

Here is the program code. Please help me.

```
public void onStart(Context paramIntent, int paramInt)
      {
        //super.onStart(paramIntent,paramInt);//ERROR IN THIS LINE
        this.dbhelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
        this.db = this.dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
        this.c = this.dbhelper.getPlaces(this.db);
        this.locManager = ((LocationManager)getSystemService("location"));
        this.db.close();
        this.am = ((AudioManager)getSystemService("audio"));
        if (this.locManager != null)
        {
          if (!this.locManager.isProviderEnabled("gps"))
          {
            startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS"));
            Toast.makeText(paramIntent, "Enable Gps!", 1).show();
          }
          this.locManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 300000L, 10.0F, this);
        }
      }
```

Comment: It should be `public void onStart(Intent intent, int paramInt)` not `public void onStart(Context paramIntent, int paramInt)`

Answer (score -1):

@Piyush Gupta wrote:

> It should be:
>
> ```
>  public void onStart(Intent intent, int paramInt)
> ```
>
> not
>
> ```
> public void onStart(Context paramIntent, int paramInt)
> ```

Comment: ([Answered in a comment and converted to a community wiki.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))